# Ubuntu 19.04 on Gnome: Randomly while typing, the system freezes and display random noise on the screen

Tags: gnome, 19.04

This sometimes happens multiple times per day and the only way to make it stop is to restart the computer. I am on a Razer Blade Stealth 2017. The screen displays random noise usually in a yellowish color and the entire display is taken up by it - none of what what previously on the screen is visible. Upon restart, there are no error messages or anything to indicate that the system crashed. The computer will not reset on its own, I need to manually restart by holding the power button. This seems to only happen while I'm in the middle of typing something regardless of the application.

Edit: After further inspection, this occurs only when the caps lock key is pressed. No matter if it's on the the built in keyboard or an external one

Comment: I'm having lag problems since installed 19.04, while not the noisy thing (i had it in 16.04 a few times). Also the mouse movement is delayed sometimes. Changing to a less resource hungry environment (xfce, icewm, i3) might solve the problem. Tried to switch on/off wayland and sometimes it helped sometimes not. Limiting other memory/cpu eaters also can help (like running only one web browser, only with a few tabs, and don't start browser+terminal+editor at the same time or at least don't try to type in the fourth application while doing it)

Comment: Does the same problem occur when you boot from an Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS LiveUSB? Please try that, then click [edit] and report the findings. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].